# Eclipselink merge does not insert a new row in many-to-many relationship

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many, eclipselink

I have a many-to-many relationship between user and role entities. when I try to merge a role by adding new user objects to that, after merging i expect a new row in the joined table (in sql server database) to be inserted but nothing happens.

I guess the problem is the direction of the relationship which the owner is User entity now and should be switched to Role. But if I change it then my spring security wont work. Is there any other way to solve this? except changing many-to-many sides?
Thanks in advance.

User class

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "SEC_USER_ROLE",
            joinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "SEC_USER_ID", referencedColumnName = "SEC_USERS")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "SEC_ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "SEC_ROLES")})
    private List<Role> roles;
```

--

Role class

```
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<User> users;
```

And here is my merge function

```
@Override
@Transactional(readOnly = false, propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED)
public T merge(T o) {

    o = em.merge(o);
    em.flush();
    return o;
}
```

Comment: Just a wild guess. Maybe you need to declare Cascade type aswell.

Comment: that was not the problem. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: You mention you are adding a new user to a new role.  Is the User inserted as well?  Have you set both sides of this bidirectional realationship, or only the Role->User relationship?  (Both sides need to be set, especially the User->Role side, as only that is reflected in the database.

Comment: im adding a User to an existing Role and yes I have included the source code here. it is bidirectional and I have set both sides